# Android v4 or v5 icons on android v6 smartphone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

How do I install old default icons form any android v4.x or v5 on android v6?
I really hate the default Marshmallow icons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want them just on your home screen and app draw you can use a custom launcher such as nova launcher, go launcher, lightning launcher, etc. Then you could use a KitKat or lollipop icon pack and change your icons that way. Another way to do this system wide is with an Xposed module called Unicon which replaces icons system-wide but requires root, Xposed, and costs money.